# variable getting a value through subscribe but not displaying in frontend

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes, frontend

I am routing from rulessetting component to feature-mapping component.
When I navigated into feature-mapping component, i am storing a dictionary in variable named feature22 by subscribing it. When i am print in console i can see that in feature22 a dic is stored but this value is not reflecting in html frontend side

component.feature-mapping.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { AlldataService } from '../alldata.service';
import { HeadingService } from '../heading.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-feature-mapping',
  templateUrl: './feature-mapping.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feature-mapping.component.css']
})
export class FeatureMappingComponent implements OnInit {
  heading:string="Rule Setting"
  features22:any={}
  features33:any =[]

  constructor(
    private allDataService:AlldataService,
    private headingService:HeadingService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.headingService.heading.emit(this.heading)
    console.log()
    this.allDataService.features22.subscribe(
      (data:any)=>{
        for(var key in data)
        {
          this.features33.push(key)
          // this.features22[key] = data[key];
        }
        // this.features22.push(...data)
        this.features22=data
        console.log("this is in rule setting")
        console.log(this.features22)
        console.log(this.features33)
      }
    )
    console.log(this.features22)
    console.log(this.features33)
  }

}
```

component.feature-mapping.html file

```
<div class="row-custom">
  <div class="section-heading1">Feature List</div>
  <div class="container1-main">
    <div> {{features33}}</div>
    <div> {{heading}}</div>
  <div class="container1" *ngFor="let feature of features22| keyvalue">
    {{feature.key}}
    <table class="table table-borderless">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody style="background-color: white;">
        <tr>
          <td scope="row" class="heading-tabledata">
            <div class="para">{{feature.key}}</div>
          </td>
          <td class="drag-tabledata">
            {{feature.value}}
          </td>
          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[In console ][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdYD9.png

[In front-end ][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgbNo.png

How I can display feature22 in html front-end ?

Comment: From what I can see, it should be binding, but I would take the following steps to debug: add `{{features22 | json}}` at the top of the template. Does that bind? 
I would also try `this.features22={...data}` in the component, does it bind then?

Comment: what is the output of these `console.logs` outside subscription? You are performing set inside subscription, but subscribe is asynchronous meaning that view tries to render `features22's` content before subscription is over and what `*ngFor` finds is empty object.

Comment: When I am printing feature22 Outside of subscription,  its blank {} dictionary, I think I should give some delay in ngOninIt so it run after html file, How to impose such delay ??

Comment: @PratishDewangan There is no problem with `feature22` initially being undefined when the view is rendered. That's what data binding is for: to update the view when the bound component data changes. Like I said, it looks like it should be binding, take a look at this StackBlitz where I mock the delay: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zfeunu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Meqwz That is not working, you have created default dictionary in that and showed in html but problem arises when we get this dictionary from service file by subscribe method. Can you show how to dealt in that case ?

Comment: @PratishDewangan Did you try the debugging steps from my original comment?

Comment: yes i tired, its not working